# Dropdown list edit review

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

So i have setup my models and controllers from my database and from the controller I have generated views. So to give you some background context, I have created an application for users to post and edits reviews about a particular service. I have made a "create" and "edit" view for the user to create a review and/or edit a review. Part of the form group in the create view allows the user to select the service that they would like to review

```
<div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WellnessService, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("WellnessService", new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Student Wellness Service", Value = "Student Wellness Service"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "HAICU", Value = "HAICU"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Student Counceling", Value = "Student Counceling"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "DISCHO ( Discrimination and Harassment  Office)", Value = "DISCHO"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Campus Protection Service (CPS)", Value = "CPS"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Disablity Service", Value = "Disability Service"},
                }, "Select Wellness Service")



                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WellnessService, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

However in the edit view, the user can the value of the service to whatever he or she pleases. I want the user to only be to change the service name of the review based on the drop down I give, instead of them typing

```
<div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rating, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

if that makes sense:P

I've read that you have to setup an enumerator in your model, there were guides available however, this is for code first mvc5 and not database first

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do it. `model` in your ViewModel, you can create a `IEnumerable<WellnessService> WellnessService { get; set; }` and pass it like this

```
var services = new List <SelectListItem> {
    new SelectListItem() {
            Text = "Student Wellness Service", Value = "Student Wellness Service"
        },
        new SelectListItem() {
            Text = "HAICU", Value = "HAICU"
        },
        new SelectListItem() {
            Text = "Student Counceling", Value = "Student Counceling"
        },
        new SelectListItem() {
            Text = "DISCHO ( Discrimination and Harassment  Office)", Value = "DISCHO"
        },
        new SelectListItem() {
            Text = "Campus Protection Service (CPS)", Value = "CPS"
        },
        new SelectListItem() {
            Text = "Disablity Service", Value = "Disability Service"
        },
}
model.WellnessServices = services;
```

Or you could put it in your ViewBag and pass like this

```
ViewBag.WellnessServices = services;
```